# How to use keystore.jks to sign and encrypt a SOAP message

Tags: java, web-services, encryption, soap

I am new to web service security and I am trying to learn how to sign and encrypt the soap message request.
I have read many posts related to this topic but it seems that there are so many different approaches that I am pretty confused which way to go.

I have a functioning web service (SOAP). I also have a keystore.jks file containing 2 entries.

The first entry type is trustedCertEntry. (X.509 / RSA public key)

The second entry type is privateKeyEntry.

My understanding is that keystore contains credentials and truststore contains a list of trusted websites (servers).
So "...\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\lib\security\cacerts" is my truststore  and keystore.jks is my keystore.

I assume I will need to use the keystore credentials to sign and encrypt the soap message.
But how to accomplish it still remains unclear to me.

I can get the X.509 certificate.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_INSTANCE);
ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());
ks.getCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
```

And I can also get the private key:

```
KeyStore.Entry entry = ks_pk.getEntry(KEYSTORE_ALIAS_PK, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pass));
```

So I can get the information from the keystore but I am not sure what to do with it in order to sign and encrypt my SOAP request message.

Do I need to add the signature as another SOAPheader element?
How do I encrypt the message?

Any pointers, code samples and tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What tools/frameworks did you use for implementation so far? If clients are supposed to send encrypted message, private key will stay at the server side(web service). The public key wrapped inside a X509 certificate will be at client side. Private key is part of a KeyStore configured on the webservice, and the public certificate is part of a TrustStore configured on the client side.

Comment: @ringbearer - thanks for your insight. I am using Eclipse Luna with Keytool plugin. I run a dummy service on tomcat-6.0.44 at localhost (in Eclipse).

Comment: Using what tools you built your client and server? CXF? Spring? Java EE ? That detail would be helpful as solutions depend on these.

Comment: @ringbearer - Oops, sorry... java EE.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Apache CXF for client and Rampart to sign and encrypt SOAP messages. This Rampart package implements the WSS standard.

In the client project add the following dependencies in pom.xml [check for the latest versions available]

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
    <artifactId>rampart-policy</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
    <artifactId>rampart-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a `crypto.properties` file which should be placed in the classpath as below:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=JKS
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file=c:/Documents and Settings/garry/keys/client.ks [this is the path to keystore]
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=client-ks-pass [this is the keystore password]
```

Then modify the Client class to provide information needed by Rampart to perform the signing

add the below imports:

```
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.SecurityConstants;
import org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback;
```

//implement the callback handler to retrieve the password

```
SService ss = new SService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
Service port = service.getPort1();
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
Map<String, Object> context = bp.getRequestContext();
//c1 is The alias of the entry in the keystore
context.put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_USERNAME, "c1");
context.put(SecurityConstants.CALLBACK_HANDLER, new CallbackHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,
    UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
                WSPasswordCallback pwcb = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
                String id = pwcb.getIdentifier();
                if (id.equals("c1")) {
                pwcb.setPassword("c1-pass");
            }
        }
    }
    });
context .put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_PROPERTIES, "crypto.properties");
```